# Asynchronous ajax calls without async=false and set delay between every call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have an ajax script that want to send ajax calls asynchronous with delay between every call and without using async=false because of freezing the browser.

here is the code:

```
function get_whois(){
    tlds.forEach(function(tld) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            //async: false,
            url: "http://example.com/script.php?domain="+$("#sld").val()+"."+tld,
            data: {}
        });
        //some stuff
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't use forEach with async calls. Instead you could use recursion or libs like async.js for example

Comment: If you control the server side code I'd strongly suggest amending it so that you can send all domains in a single request, instead of flooding the server with N requests in very quick succession

Comment: @VladimirG Can you guide me more by giving a code sample of your solution? I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible options is using recursion:

```
function get_whois(tlds){
    // assume tlds is array
    if(tlds.length==0) return;
    var tld = tlds.shift();
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        //async: false,
        url: "http://example.com/script.php?domain="+$("#sld").val()+"."+tld,
        data: {}
    }).done(function () {
        // your stuff here
        setTimeout(function () {
            get_whois(tlds)
        }, 1000 /* wait for a second*/)
    }).fail(/*handle error*/)
}
```

Or you can use [async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

```
each(tlds, function (tld, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        //async: false,
        url: "http://example.com/script.php?domain="+$("#sld").val()+"."+tld,
        data: {}
    }).done(function () {
        // your stuff here
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback();
        }, 1000 /* wait for a second*/)
    }).fail(function (err) {
        /*handle error*/
        done(err)
    })
}, function(err){
    // your loop is done
});
```

Also pay attention for what @rory-mccrossan said. Do you really need to do all of this requests or maybe you can combine it to one?